# No code emitted when including definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, typescript-typings

I've been working on converting a NodeJS application to typescript and I can't seem to get the MongoDB type definitions to work properly.

Typescript is fine with both of these:

```
const _mongodb = require( "mongodb" ); 
import * as MongoDB from "mongodb";
```

The first one will include the actually node module and will work once the code has been transpiled, but it doesn't include any type definitions.

The second one includes the types, but doesn't appear to include the node module. In fact if I use the second one then none of the code is emitted at all. All of the correct files are output and `tsc` takes a second or so to run, but the files are completely empty.

This is an older project and it used `npm` to install mongodb. From the projects `package.json` the mongodb version is: `"mongodb": "^2.1.0-alpha"`.

I used `typings` to install the definition file with the command: `typings install dt~mongodb --save --global`.

I'm in a bit of a rush right now so if you need anymore details, just ask and I'll happily add them later.

## Edit

I just remembered. I also have `/// <referernce path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` at the top of the file in question. With out it typescript complains about the `"mongodb"` string in the second import.

I guess this is because the mongodb typings file has a module that contains the definitions, but doesn't link up with the node module in anyway?